# How to initialize an array variable inside a structure?

Tags: c, struct

I want to initialize a couple of arrays which are members of a struct which is passed to a function by reference.
Appreciate any help.

```
typedef struct Snake_pos
{
    char field[10][10];
    int Y[10];
    int X[10];
}snake_pos;

int main()
{
    snake_pos pos1;
    pos_init(&pos1);
    return 0;
}

void pos_init(snake_pos *pos1)
{
    pos1->X={};
    pos1->Y={};
    pos1->field={};
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use the syntax `= {}` when defining the variable. So to zero every member you can either define it as

```
snake_pos pos1 = { 0 };
```

Or if it is passed to a function, like this

```
void pos_init(snake_pos *pos1)
{
    memset(pos1, 0, sizeof *pos1);
}
```

Comment: Both the answers are wrong. It is not defining, it is initializing.
Second, inside the function you are doing memset of 0, which will work only if the user wants to set 0.

Comment: @JayKumarR OP's question was about **initialising**, specifically the use of `{}` in a function which was passed a **defined** variable. I posted two solutions. In the first case `snake_pos pos1 = { 0 };` is a **definition** which also **initialises**, and the data would be easy to change. In the second case the function would be passed a **defined** variable to **initialise**, but since he did not state what values to **initialise** I gave the trivial solution, which he was happy to accept. If you can post a better answer, please edit your earlier one and revive it instead of downvoting me.

Comment: 1) If OP's question was about initializing, then you should not mislead him by saying 'use the syntax = {} when defining'. 
2) The OP did not say he want everything to be '0'. So the memset is useless for all datatypes except char and zero values. 
3)  If you just want to help him using a trick,then write in comments and give proper answer in answer section.

Comment: Oh for heaven's sake, just post a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

> You can access any array element inside of an array through a
>   structure pointer this way :
>
> - for **1 D** array :
>     `structure_pointer->array_valiable[index1]`
> - for **2 D** array :
>     `structure_pointer->array_valiable[index1][index2]`

---

so now, you can initialize each member of arrays `X` , `Y` and `field` of structure `snake_pos` using `scanf()` this way :

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct Snake_pos
{
    char field[10][10];
    int Y[10];
    int X[10];

}snake_pos;

void pos_init(snake_pos *pos1)
{
    int i,j;

    //initializing each member

    //of array X
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        scanf("%d",&pos1->X[i]);

    //of array Y
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        scanf("%d",&pos1->Y[i]);

    //of the two dimensional array field
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
            scanf(" %c",&pos1->field[i][j]); 
    //notice the space before %c is to consume white spaces returning from before scanf's
}


int main()
{


      snake_pos pos1;
      pos_init(&pos1);

  return 0;
}
```

---

> **Note :** if you want to initialize all members to a single fixed value,
>   then you can instead of using scanf() in for loop, assign the value
>   this way :
>
> ```
>   for(i=0;i<10;i++) //initializes all members with a value of 0
>       pos1->X[i]=0;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialize with zero's, Why not memset the structure ?

```
void pos_init(snake_pos *pos1)
{
    memset(pos1, 0, sizeof(snake_pos));
}
```